# How to make image responsive in navbar html + css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using this code

```html
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img class="img-logo" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png" alt="" loading="lazy" style="width:12%;height:auto; float: left;">
          <h1 style="color: #89216b; float: right; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; font-size: all;">Trendings</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

All is perfect but when i see it on mobile image size is small and text size remains same I just want that Image size will not be small

Comment: remove `width: 12%` from `.img-logo`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov after removing with size of the image is big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on what you have,.. you are using some css framework since you have :

`d-flex flex-row etc`

If so why use inline styling? ...Anyhow if you are going to style anything then edit the image:

```
.img-logo {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100px;
}
```

or inline...

```
<img class="img-logo" src="img" alt="" loading="lazy" style="
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
">
```

100px is just my example you can do correct size by your will. That would be your image style so it can look fine at any size.

Comment: When I use your code float left in logo and float right in P not working

Comment: you have lost me I did this for your image... I know nothing about your P tag...

Answer (score 1):

When you use **width:12%** in **img** it made image smaller automatically. So I suggested you to remove that code and use this one instead;

```
.navbar-brand{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;  
}
.img-logo{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

Also in your html;(I removed **width** and **height** in style)

```
<img class="img-logo" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png" alt="" loading="lazy" style="float: left;">
```